# Can't start figwheel REPL inside Cider in emacs

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, cider

I am using cider with figwheel , to start cider i use cider-jack-in-clj&cljs and choose figwheel

[image]

I can see clj cider gets started and then cljs but cljs cider can't connect to emacs.
However I can connect my application to cljs cider but emacs can't connect to cljs cider.

my cider-version , 0.21

[cider/piggieback "0.3.10"]

[figwheel-sidecar "0.5.16"]

Any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer, its because I need to update my dependency to [figwheel-sidecar "0.5.18"] and add :repl-options {:nrepl-middleware [cider.piggieback/wrap-cljs-repl]}

Comment: Thanks, I need to wait 48 hours to accept my own answer :)